# Possessive Time Period

Tags: grammar, possessives

We have some guide text on our website that reads:

> This email will send daily to members whose vouchers are expiring in 10 days time

However a colleague is insisting that the time period is possessive so the sentence should read:

> This email will send daily to members whose vouchers are expiring in 10 **days'** time

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

Comment: This email ***will be sent*** daily to members whose vouchers are expiring within 10 days.

Comment: @Jim is right about the passive (*will be sent*), and your colleague is right about the possessive.